# Cascading soft deletes without loading entire relationship in Ef Core

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, .net-core

I was working on cascading soft deletes to related entities. I have the following solution so far but it requires that I load the related data using Include, ThenInclude ... in order to work. Is there a better way to achieve the same thing? The problem is if I forgot to load a related data the corresponding Delete method will raise null exception.

```
public class Entity1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Entity2> Entity2s { get; set; }
       
       public void Delete()
        {
            if (IsDeleted == null)
            {
                Name = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}${Name}";
                IsDeleted = DateTime.Now;

                foreach (var entity2 in Entity2s) // this raises null reference exception if Entity2s is not loaded
                {
                    entity2.Delete();
                }
         }
    }
```

```
public class Entity2
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Entity3> Entity3s{ get; set; }
       
       public void Delete()
        {
            if (IsDeleted == null)
            {
                Name = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}${Name}";
                IsDeleted = DateTime.Now;

                foreach (var entity3 in Entity3s) // this raises null reference exception if Entity3s is not loaded
                {
                    entity3.Delete();
                }
         }
    }
```

Then on delete I have

```
var ent = await _context.Entity1.Include(x => x.Entity2s)
                               .ThenInclude(x => x.Entity3s)
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

                ent.Delete();

   await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

This example is only between 3 entities but in the real application there are a lots of relations. So for each relation I have to do Include, ThenInclude ...  Please help. I really appreciate it if you could also point me to a better solution. I have googled this but so far I couldnt find the right solution for this.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to delete a tree of related data without looking at it to discover the dependent entities. Doing it as a stored proc where the update that soft deletes a dependent entity returns the IDs of those entities so the soft delete change be propagated to them might be the closest thing. The other option is to just delete the parent entity and then check the tree when you load it - use injected filters to only load entities that are not soft deleted. The child entities won't load for a parent that is deleted(but they would load if you bypassed the parent/loaded them direct)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are applying business logic to the delete process, such as in recording the deletion time and renaming deleted items then this is pretty much going to be the mechanism to delete them. Putting the Delete as a domain action in the entity like you have I would recommend enabling lazy loading as this would ensure that it can run reliably as you'd expect it would only be called while the entity is in scope of a DbContext. Eager loading is certainly recommended, but entities can reasonably assure that a delete operation will succeed if something is forgotten. (Better to have a "sub-optimal" performance bug than a operation cancelling bug)

If you want to disable lazy loading entirely then I would consider moving the Delete method out of the entity and into a Repository or service method that ensures that the provided entity and related entities are loaded then proceeds to perform the delete operation on the entire graph. The entities can still use an internal `Delete()` method to standardize the setting of the date and rename if necessary, just not worry about the graph, that would be the responsibility of the Repository/service. This way your controller or such code might "see" an entity, but cannot call Delete, they must use the Service to delete entities at whatever level is supported and the service ensures that the relevant entity graph is updated.

Comment: Ok thank you. Really grateful for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a more generic approach in the past by overriding the `SaveChanges()` and `SaveChangesAsync()` EF methods in the DbContext.cs class as follows...

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    UpdateDateTrackingColumns();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    UpdateDateTrackingColumns();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
}

private void UpdateDateTrackingColumns()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (!entry.CurrentValues.EntityType.ToString().Contains("Identity"))
        {
            switch (entry.Metadata.Name)
            {
                // Entities where there is no DateCreated, DateUpdated, or DateDeleted columns in the entity are processed this way...
                // For example, EF Core generated many-to-many intersect tables will not have these columns.
                case "IgnoreTheseEntities": // Exclude entities by listing them as 'case "EntityName":' lines.
                    break;
                // All entities with DateCreated, DateUpdated, and DateDeleted columns are processed in this way...
                default:
                    var saveUtcDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    switch (entry.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Added:
                            entry.CurrentValues["DateCreated"] = saveUtcDate;
                            entry.CurrentValues["DateUpdated"] = saveUtcDate;
                            entry.CurrentValues["DateDeleted"] = DateTime.MinValue;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            entry.CurrentValues["DateUpdated"] = saveUtcDate;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Deleted:
                            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                            entry.CurrentValues["DateDeleted"] = saveUtcDate;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Probably worth noting that in the example above I was also using Microsoft Identity Framework... these tables don't have the date columns by default.  So I chose to ignore these tables, hence the `if (!entry.CurrentValues.EntityType.ToString().Contains("Identity"))` clause.  You can remove this `if` clause if you're not using Identity Framework.

**[Edit]** You may also need to worry about `DeleteBehaviour`.  You can prevent cascading deletes using something like the following in `EntityTypeConfiguration` classes...

```
builder
    .HasMany(p => p.Teams)
    .WithOne(d => d.Location)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

You may also want to add query filters to each of your entities.  This will then prevent soft deleted rows being returned by EF queries.  I use `EntityTypeConfiguration` classes to handle these.  An example of this would look like...

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Common.Models;
using System;

namespace MyQT.DAL.EntityTypeConfiguration
{
    public class AddressTypeEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AddressType>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AddressType> builder)
        {
            builder
                .Property(b => b.AddressTypeId)
                .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .IsRequired()
                .HasComment("Unique identifier for a given AddressType.");
            builder
                .Property(b => b.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(200)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasComment("The AddressType name.");
            builder
                .Property(b => b.DateCreated)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasComment("The UTC date/time that the row was inserted into the database.");
            builder
                .Property(b => b.DateUpdated)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasComment("The UTC date/time that any given row was last updated. Upon record creation this will be set to DateCreated value.");
            builder
                .Property(b => b.DateDeleted)
                .HasComment("The UTC date/time that any given row was \"deleted\".  Data is NOT actually deleted.  It will instead be \"archived\" by populating the DateDeleted for any given row.");
            builder
                .Property(b => b.TimeStamp)
                .IsRowVersion()  // Alternatively use ".IsConcurrencyToken()"... similar but different
                .HasComment("Concurrency token.");

            // Soft delete automated query filter
            builder
                .HasQueryFilter(m => EF.Property<DateTime>(m, "DateDeleted") == DateTime.MinValue);
                // Possible better way...
                //.HasQueryFilter(p => p.DateDeleted.Value == DateTime.MinValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have seen a similar approach. But will this work if I dont Include, ThenInclude ... related entities before removing the data and saving the changes?

Comment: I think you're referring to cascading deletes?  I have edited answer to include something on this.  In a bit of a rush due to work commitments but I hope it gets you there... I'll tidy it up a bit later.

Comment: I've just realised what you meant by ThenInclude(). The rows will only be marked as "Deleted" once SaveChanges() has been called. If you don't want the deleted rows to feature in EF query results you must add the ```.HasQueryFilter()``` method . If you try to query an entity using the ```.Include()``` or ```.ThenInclude()``` methods before you have ```SavedChanges()```, then logically because the changes have not been committed to the database, the entity ```.HasQueryFilter()``` will not filter these soft deleted rows out.  Apologies if I misinterpreted/missed this in your original question.

Comment: Really thanks again for taking time to replay. I have the query filter already. But the problem I have is when I soft delete an entity, I want to do the same for related entities too. In the solution I have , I have to load the related entities to memory using (.Include() or .ThenInclude()) to apply the soft delete. But this doesnt seem right, because if I forget to load a related entity then that means it wont be deleted.

Comment: I agree this doesn’t feel right. Are you using the ```.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.**Option**);``` method?  The DeleteBehavior enum has an option called ClientCascade. This might be what you’re looking for.

Here’s the Microsoft page on the subject. You should find it discussed about halfway down under the heading of “ Database cascade limitations”.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#